# Node-Red Function Nodes In Sequence

Tags: node-red, flow-based-programming

Hi I am currently developing a system in Node-Red. So it will receive input from POST and it will process it in the JS function node. But this is where the question begins. So if I put all the logics in one function node it will take like 100 lines of code (which now works btw). Should I just keep this or do I need to make several(like 2 or 3) function nodes in order to process the information in a sequential manner or is there no such need to do so? So instead of just having 3 nodes in a flow (receive input, function node to process logic, and output), should I separate the logic? (receive input, function node #1, function node #2, function node #n, and output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how do you want to organize your graph. Sometimes split in several nodes is better for maintenance and reuse the function in other flows.

Once I see node-red is a solution for prototype, POC etc, if you want to move it to production or it is getting too complex I recommend do it in NodeJs.

Comment: I know it's been a month since I come back to this post. It's just a simple project so I do segment the flows a little bit so I can use the required modules every time and everywhere. Thanks !